# Safari History gets deleted after a while?

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

Okay, I've had this problem for like 2 years and I'm absolutely pissed off about it. For some reason, (even though I have set "Delete History" to "Manual") my Safari history keeps getting deleted. For example, my oldest entry is 2015, 29 January. Yesterday when I checked it, the oldest date was 2015, 28 January. So for everyday that goes, it keeps deleting my history!

Why does this problem occur? And before you say that I should delete my history file; I already did, I tried that back in October but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Type `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist HistoryAgeInDaysLimit` into a Terminal window and tell us the result.

Comment: "365000" was the result

Comment: There you go. 365 days. It must truncate the trailing zeros, maybe? See [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/edit?id=4964) for more info about the value you can set for `HistoryAgeInDaysLimit`. I would guess that setting it to 999999 would max it out. Datatype is integer, so it could be larger. Btw/ 999999 days is 2737.91 years.

Comment: Sorry @IconDaemon but I don't think so. Test it on your own Mac. 365000 is the correct value if you set it to Manual. If you set it to a year the value is 365. At least in my testing. So, for some reason it is ignoring this setting.