# Safari history disappears despite settings

Tags: safari, backup, web-browser, history, browser-history

I like to have my browser history span years back so I can look at things which may have interested me a long time ago. To pursue this desire, I have set Safari to remove history items "manually" under the `General` tab in the `Preferences`. I have done the same thing for download list items. My intent was (and is) to not remove history items ever and to keep Safari from doing it automatically.

This seemed to be working fine for a while, and I still have history which goes back more than a year. However, I have recently noticed that the oldest days in my history are disappearing. At first I wasn't sure, but after conducting some tests I am sure. It seems to happen randomly and infrequently. I think that the Safari window also loses focus when it happens.

I am not sure how or why this is happening. The only thing I can think of is that there may be some hard-coded limit in Safari itself. Or perhaps it purges old history items when it reaches a memory limit.

I see that my `History.db` file is 80MiB in `ls` output:

```
  -rw-r--r--    1 my_username staff  80M Dec 29 13:02 History.db
```

Is 80MiB some sort of implicit limit for Safari?

Another troubling facet of this issue is that I cannot export my Safari history to another browser. Both Chrome and Firefox refuse to import anything from Safari except bookmarks. Moreover, I do not have many backups of my Safari history. Although, backups would not help too much anyway since a backup would lack my recent history.

So how can I get Safari to stop losing my oldest history items?

Some environment info:

My Safari version is currently 11.0.2 on macOS 10.13.2. Also, I am not using iCloud integration with Safari.

**EDIT:**

At the time of the bounty on this question, I will also consider accepting answers which offer a way to export my history to another browser (preferably Firefox or Chrome).

Comment: Have you checked for any similar question on here ? Such as : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/178969/237687

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I have looked for similar questions here and elsewhere. Funnily enough, I stumbled upon that question you linked to *after* I posted my question here. I could not find it before posting my question here and I have tried to apply some advice in the comments of that question. Namely, I have run: `defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist HistoryAgeInDaysLimit 999999`. I am not yet sure if this will work, esp. since this advice was not an accepted answer.

Comment: A similar question was given the suggestion of a chron script to store each day / week copied to a separate file as backup... can’t find it at the moment tho’.

Comment: @SolarMike That is an interesting idea. I certainly would like to know more about it.

Comment: Well, have search you may find it before me...

Comment: @SolarMike I did not find the suggestion about cron, but I can confirm that the advice in the question you linked to does not work. I still lose history even after setting `HistoryAgeInDaysLimit` to `999999`.

Comment: As near as I can tell, if you sync Safari history in iCloud, your macOS history will be [truncated to match a smaller size limit imposed by any other devices](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/419276/4395) (e.g. iOS) that re synced with. This makes no sense of course, but it appears to be what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is size limit imposed by *Safari*.

A sqlite database can obviously be larger than 80M; it is only limited by the amount of available storage space, but technically it has an upper [file size limit of about 140TB](https://sqlite.org/limits.html)

Other developers have noted that in (older versions of) Safari, [the limit is capped at 50GB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2377391/4703819).  It's reasonable to assume that this limit has been increased in subsequent releases of macOS/iOS/Safari.

It also stands to reason that this size limit is imposed by (Apple) Safari because, by default, it is configured to synchronize with iCloud to other Apple devices many of which are constrained by storage availability (iPhones and iPads, for example).

We also know that [iCloud's basic (free) storage allotment is 5GB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201238) and this must account for much more than browsing history.  Things like files, settings, device backups (where applicable) keychains, notes, etc. must be allocated space.  Synchronization of these items is set by default by Apple.

It wouldn't make much sense to allow an unlimited history  where `History.db`could outstrip the capacity of iCloud/iPad/iPhone.

Even though ***you're not using iCloud integration***, the average user does and Apple will architect it's products around this premise and design their products accordingly.

**Extracting Your History**

You can pull your history items out of the `History.db` file with this (very) simple sqlite3 script

Create a "commands.txt" file and populate it with the following commands:

```
.mode csv
.once history.txt
select visit_time, title, url from history_visits inner join history_items on history_items.id = history_visits.history_item;
```

Then issue the command

```
sqlite3 History.db < commands.txt
```

This will create a CSV file called `history.txt` containing the time, title and URL of the history items.  This assumes you are in the `~/Library/Safari` directory.  Keep in mind that the date/time of your history item will be in [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (although the epoch [is different in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167003/what-format-is-the-safari-history-db-history-visits-visit-time-in)) and will need to be ultimately converted.

Comment: This is useful information and it's good to know that this limit is imposed by Safari on purpose. At least it's not some crazy bug. Yet, I would still prefer a way to get around this limitation so that I can still use Safari. But if no better answer appears, I guess this will be the best one.

Comment: Well, I just tried your script since no new answers have appeared. Strangely, it doesn't seem to work. The resultant `history.txt` file is completely empty.

Comment: If you *manually* enter the select command in `sqlite3` do you see anything?

Comment: No, there is no output when I do that either.

Comment: Just so we're on the same page.... `sqlite3 History.db`, then `select * from history_items;`  Let me know what you get.

Comment: That yields a massive dump of my history items.

Comment: I’ll have to look at it when I get back as I’m on my iPhone now and I can’t test

Comment: Allan, I'm sorry that the bounty expired before I got the chance to award you full points. You received half of the award, but I didn't know whether I should give you the full amount since your script isn't working yet. I apologize as I also had a family emergency to attend to and wasn't able to be more attentive to getting your script to work. I will give you an upvote for all your effort and I really hope we can get your script working so that I can at least have a more workable format for my history. Please offer any more advice if possible; I will accept your answer once your script works.

Comment: I think I have a clue as to what is going wrong with your SQL script. It looks like there is no `url` item in my `history_visits` table. I used [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to inspect the database and find this out.

Comment: Allan, do you plan on looking at this issue any further? I would appreciate further help as I am not quite sure what the issue is thus far and I would really like to get my Safari history extracted as soon as possible.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I ended up with the flu for a better part of a week which put me a week behind all my other projects.  It's taken me for what seems like forever to get back up to speed on everything.  I typed in the the wrong field name in the the `select` command.  Try it now.  I just tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: So sorry about your flu! It's been going around where I live too and it's certainly a yucky thing to deal with. Also, your new set of commands works great and I've got a workable `history.txt` file now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, no you cannot.

I suggest you use Chrome and import your data with these steps:

1. install and start Chrome (close Safari)
2. Click on the 3 dots on the Top-right corner
3. Drag your cursor to "Bookmarks" then click on "Import Bookmarks and Settings"
4. You'll see 4 options, it is Select items to import: "Browsing history" "Favorites/Bookmarks" "Saved passwords" "Search engines"

Comment: [This is all I see](https://cl.ly/090U3E2U1J2s/import.png) when I try to import things from Safari to Chrome.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how this answers the question?

Comment: 1. Chrome cannot import Safari history as of now 2. Chrome also deletes history older than 90 days. 3. Best alternative is FF which gives user the ability to set the expiry date/number https://superuser.com/questions/1635171/firefox-doesnt-import-all-history-from-chrome/1635172#1635172 but that's not helpful for this question

Comment: Thanks, Sherlock; You're three years late for the discussion.